# Android Room LiveData select query parameters

Tags: android, android-room

I decided to teach myself Java and Android by doing a simple database app. I already implemented some functionality the "lazy" way - all selects are done on the main thread.

Now I want to use LiveData for selects. I've read the [simplistic training guide on android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) and implemented [a more complex solution from codelabs guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view), with LiveData and RecyclerView. Inserts, updates, deletes, and selects *for whole tables* work flawlessly, however I have no idea how to pass parameters to selects.

Example: I have an activity with scrollable list of all records and I want to apply some filters to the list (search). From what I understand the actual select method from DAO is called only once (when ViewModel is created), so **how do I update query with new parameters?**

Other example: I have other activity that displays all columns of a record (for viewing and editing). **How do I pass id to query to select a single row?**

My database code is more less the same as in [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#15)

**Edit:** I finally did it like that: every time I want to update query parameters I call select from DAO (through ViewModel and Repo) and add a new observer to that new list. This solution doesn't seem optimal but I guess it works...

Comment: you can have multiple select statements with **Dao**

Comment: I thought of that, but let's say I want a text field in which user can type any search string

Comment: so ? whats the issue here ?? though these doesnt require a select statement.

Comment: you have your list from **select all** statement...then from that whole list filter the list which the user searches...and show the searched list

Comment: hmmm... so basically filter using java not sql... maybe I'll try. Thanks for the idea

Comment: yes..there are a lot of demos.. you can do whichever way you feel like.. :) it depends upon the function

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think your solution is a Transformations.switchMap. The simplest example how it may works in the case from codelab

```
public class WordViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private WordRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Word>> mAllWords;
    private LiveData<List<Word>> searchByLiveData;
    private MutableLiveData<String> filterLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public WordViewModel (Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new WordRepository(application);
        mAllWords = mRepository.getAllWords();
        searchByLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(filterLiveData, 
                                                     v -> mRepository.searchBy(v));
    }

    LiveData<List<Word>> getSearchBy() { return searchByLiveData; }
    void setFilter(String filter) { filterLiveData.setValue(filter); }
    LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords() { return mAllWords; }
    public void insert(Word word) { mRepository.insert(word); }
}
```

So, when you set filter value, it will change value of searchByLiveData

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Finally got some time to try your solution and it works wonderfully! Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In repository.searchBy(v) it must be **mRepository**?

Comment: @mjn42 yes, i fix it. regarding the error, show me the code and perhaps i will be able to help you

Comment: in the line void setFilter(String filter) { filterLiveData.value = filter; } the ".value" does not exist in filterLiveData

Comment: @mjn42 setValue, sure

Comment: @basilkot it was helpful for me where I had to fetch data from Room based on various sort options selected by the user. Earlier, I was doing it in a very unusual way. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! This has resolved a fair bit of headache for me :)

Comment: Your code helped a lot. But there is a problem in the line : `private LiveData<String> filterColor = new MutableLiveData<String>();`instead use `private MutableLiveData<String> filterColor = new MutableLiveData<String>(); `because the **LiveData's** `setValue()` has a protected access while **MutableLiveData's** `setValue()` has a public access.

Comment: have save mylife