# ViewModel - change parameter of method while observing LiveData at runtime?

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm trying to figure out MVVM (It's very new for me) and I figured out how to observe LiveData using Room and ViewModel. Now I am facing a problem.

I have a Room query which requires parameter and this is how I start observing the LiveData in onCreate in MainActivity.

```
    String color = "red";
    myViewModel.getAllCars(color).observe(this, new Observer<List<Car>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Car> cars) {
                adapter.setCars(cars);
            }
        });
```

By using this code, I recieve list of "red" cars and populate RecyclerView with the List.

Now to my question - is there a way to change the `color` variable inside the `getAllCars` method (for example by button click) and affect the observer to return new List? If i simply change the color variable, nothing happens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669526/10648865), your solution is `Transformation.switchMap`

From [Android for Developers website:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations)

> LiveData< Y > switchMap (LiveData< X > trigger, Function< X, LiveData< Y >> func)
>
> Creates a LiveData, let's name it swLiveData, which follows next flow: it reacts on
> changes of trigger LiveData, applies the given function to new value
> of trigger LiveData and sets resulting LiveData as a "backing"
> LiveData to swLiveData. "Backing" LiveData means, that all events
> emitted by it will retransmitted by swLiveData.

In your situation, it would look something like this:

```
public class CarsViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private CarRepository mCarRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Car>> mAllCars;
    private LiveData<List<Car>> mCarsFilteredByColor;
    private MutableLiveData<String> filterColor = new MutableLiveData<String>();
    
    public CarsViewModel (CarRepository carRepository) {
        super(application);
        mCarRepository= carRepository;
        mAllCars = mCarRepository.getAllCars();
        mCarsFilteredByColor = Transformations.switchMap(
            filterColor,
            color -> mCarRepository.getCarsByColor(color)
        );
    }
    
    LiveData<List<Car>>> getAllCars() { return mAllCars; }
    LiveData<List<Car>> getCarsFilteredByColor() { return mCarsFilteredByColor; }

    // When you call this function to set a different color, it triggers the new search
    void setFilter(String color) { filterColor.setValue(color); }
}
```

So when you call the `setFilter` method from your view, changing the filterColor LiveData will triger the Transformation.switchMap, which will call `mRepository.getCarsByColor(c))` and then update with the query's result the mCarsFilteredByColor LiveData. Hence, if you are observing this list in your view and you set a different color, the observer receive the new data.

Comment: it was helpful for me where I had to fetch data from Room based on various sort options selected by the user. Earlier, I was doing it in a very unusual way. Thanks!

Comment: Your code helped a lot. But there is a problem in the line : `private LiveData<String> filterColor = new MutableLiveData<String>();`instead  use `private MutableLiveData<String> filterColor = new MutableLiveData<String>();` because the **LiveData's** `setValue()` has a protected access while **MutableLiveData's** `setValue()` has a public access.

Comment: @SayokMajumder you are right, thanks! Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Other than @dglozano answer, one easy way to do this is to observe the `color` instead of observing the `list`. And on `valueChange` of `color`, fetch new list.

Example:

In `ViewModel` class do this

```
MutableLiveData<String> myColor = new MutableLiveData<String>();
```

In `Activity` do this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v)
{
    myViewModel.myColor.setValue("newColor");
} });

myViewModel.myColor.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String newValue) {
           // do this on dedicated thread
           List<Car> updateList = myViewModel.getCarsByColor(newValue)
           // update the RecyclerView
        }
    });
```

**Note**: 1.The `getCarsByColor()` need not to be wrapped as `LiveData`. The method in `Dao` can return `List<Cars>` instead of `LiveData<List<Cars>>`.

2.Don't run the db queries on main thread, and do call the `notifyDataSetChanged` to refresh the RecyclerView.

Comment: Don't know what u r trying to achieve here. Why do u have to use an observer to "observe" color when u already know about the change in its value, via the onClick method? In a sense, u r setting a value yourself and then getting the same via the observer which is pointless.